# Command not found when running a local executable from csh script

Tags: shell, executable, csh

My current project involves the use of a .go executable written on Fortran 77 in the mid-eighties.  My only access to it currently is through ssh to a server using csh.  I have written the following script:

```
set inpdir = $argv[1]
mkdir ${inpdir}"_out"
set j = 1
while ($j <= 5)
    set i = 0
    while ($i <= 20)
        "tms96-fnl.go <./"${inpdir}"/inp"${j}"0"${i}".d> ./"${inpdir}"_out/out"${j}"0"${i}
        set i = i + 1
    end
    set j = j + 1
end
```

The result is the message:

```
tms96-fnl.go <./fftf/inp100.d> ./fftf_out/out100 -Command not found
Syntax error
```

If i were to key the contents of that message (sans the "-Command not found") while in the same working directory as the script it executes as expected.

Comment: Is that exactly the script you're running? How did it generate the `.d` at the end of the input file name shown in the error message?

Comment: You're right sorry.  I had to key it in manually because the server I'm using is locked down pretty tight and I can't scp.  Edited above.

Comment: I think the problem is the arrangement of quotes perhaps. You have `"tms96-fnl.go <./"${inpdir}"/inp"${j}"0"${i}".d> ./"${inpdir}"_out/out"${j}"0"${i}` which might be interpreted as a command that looks like `"tms96-fnl.go <./"`. I would try: `tms96-fnl.go < ./"${inpdir}"/inp"${j}"0"${i}".d > ./${inpdir}"_out/out"${j}"0"${i}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the arrangement of quotes. You have:

```
"tms96-fnl.go <./"${inpdir}"/inp"${j}"0"${i}".d> ./"${inpdir}"_out/out"${j}"0"${i}
```

Which would interpret a command that looks like `tms96-fnl.go <./`. I would do:

```
tms96-fnl.go < ./"${inpdir}"/inp"${j}"0"${i}".d > ./"${inpdir}"_out/out"${j}"0"${i}"
```